# Controller method not working: how to find related record in related model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Member model that is related to an Organization model: 1 organization has many members. In the controller method below I try to find an organization in line 3 to set its status to activated in line .

However, when running tests I get the error message `NoMethodError: undefined method 'organization_id' for nil:NilClass`. I don't think though that member is nil. Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
  def edit
    member = Member.find_by(email: params[:email])
    organization = Organization.find_by(params[:member.organization_id])
    if member && !member.activated? && member.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      member.activate
      log_in("member", member)
      flash[:success] = "Account activated! You can now update your profile."
      redirect_to member
      organization.update_attributes(activated: true) unless organization.activated?
    elsif user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in("user", user)
      flash[:success] = "Account activated! You can now update your profile."
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: `params` is like a hash, if you want to access values inside it, use `params[:member]`, maybe the organization_id you're looking for is contained in `params[:member][:organization_id]`..?

Comment: Tried `organization = Organization.find_by(params[:member][:organization_id])`. This produced the error `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
member = Member.find_by(email: params[:email])
organization = Organization.find_by(params[:member.organization_id])
```

You already have the `member`, the `ActiveRecord::Associations` will do the magic:

```
member = Member.find_by(email: params[:email])
if member
  organization = member.organization
else
  #whatever
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on that line. instead of calling

```
organization = Organization.find_by(params[:member.organization_id])
```

you need to just directly call `member.oranization_id`

```
organization = Organization.find_by(member.organization_id)
```

however this can be simplified even further using active records association functions

```
organization = member.organization
```